# uitableview style is grouped but section headers don't scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this in viewDidLoad

```
UITableView * table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
self.tableView = table;
```

This code might also be relevant

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {


if( [view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]] )
{
    ((UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view).textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123.0/255.0 green:21.0/255.0 blue:31.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    ((UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view).contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

}

but the section headers still don't scroll until after I scroll past the cell. I am trying to make the section headers behave like normal text in a tableview cell. When I scroll up, I want them to immediately start moving up and out of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going into interface builder clicking on tableview and then style -> Grouped fixed the issue. Not sure why doing it programmatically wasn't working